# State of C++11 standard support in libc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, libc++

Is there a good source of information on C++11 standard support in libc++? Its web site says 98% of the standard is supported but I'd like to know what features the other 2% are.

Something similar to this list for libstdc++ would be nice: 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: Which library are you talking about? [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) (from LLVM/Clang) or [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) (from GNU)?

Comment: Uhm.. it takes a few seconds to find it in google... the clang page has links to libc++, and the linked page mentions that the major missing piece is `<atomic>`... a graph shows that there are also a few utilities that are not yet fully compliant.

Comment: for gcc look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** From [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681403/state-of-c11-standard-support-in-libc/11686748#comment15497309_11686748)'s comment below:

> The chart is outdated already. I should update it or take it down. The only thing unimplemented in libc++ right now is 20.7.2.5 `shared_ptr` atomic access [util.smartptr.shared.atomic]. And I hope to get that done this weekend. [atomics] is there now. Oh, `quick_exit` is missing. I'm going to let the C library implement that.

---

The most recent and detailed information is already linked from the [front page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) (doesn't mean it is new enough ☺).

> The only major missing piece of C++'0x support is `<atomic>`.
>
> [Here](http://libcxx.llvm.org/libcxx_by_chapter.pdf) is a by-chapter breakdown of what is passing tests and what isn't.
>
> [image]

We can see that 76% of `<atomic>`, 3% of "[language.support]" and 2% of "[utilities]" are missing.

I don't think there would be more updated/detailed break down like the libstdc++ one.

Comment: This is *very* old information. I would highly doubt its accuracy, as Clang was recently improved very much in the `<atomic>` department. Check the test suite in the atomics department, run it (I can't, I don't have a Mac) and see for yourself. I ran the test suite on a thrown together setup on Windows, and [all Atomics tests pass](http://libcxx.llvm.org/results.Windows.html) with Clang built on MinGW-w64. This obviously does not mean you can *use* libc++ with Clang on Windows :(

Comment: While I really like this answer, the graph is (hopefully) going to become outdated quickly. Then again, so is the question...

Comment: The chart is outdated already.  I should update it or take it down.  The only thing unimplemented in libc++ right now is 20.7.2.5 shared_ptr atomic access [util.smartptr.shared.atomic].  And I hope to get that done this weekend.  [atomics] is there now.  Oh, quick_exit is missing.  I'm going to let the C library implement that.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: You should make that an answer :)

Comment: @KennyTM:  I upvoted yours instead.  It was easier and saved me time. :-)

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted to know.

Comment: [util.smartptr.shared.atomic] is checked into trunk.

Answer (score 5):

A frustrating side note on `std::quick_exit()` and `std::at_quick_exit()` functions. They are still unimplemented in macOS's **libc** even after several years. Also there is a possible vulnerability in the C++ standard, where it states you can safely call `std::quick_exit()` from a signal handler, but it doesn't state the functions that are registered by `std::at_quick_exit()` must also meet the same requirements a regular signal handler does. I believe that might be the reason behind why those functions are not implemented yet.